# WndProc get typed character

Tags: winapi

I need help with this, basically what I want to do is create text input fields, I need to make my program know when I pressed any key on keyboard, then get typed character and add typed character to existing std::string variable

I tried to search a lot, but I haven't found any solution to my problem
I need to be typed character same as I type on keyboard in current keyboard language like (č'ˇ°)...

```
std::string text;
MSG msg;

LRESULT CALLBACK Hooked_WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        g_Menu.keys[VK_LBUTTON] = true;
        break;
    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        g_Menu.keys[VK_LBUTTON] = false;
        break;
    case WM_RBUTTONDOWN:
        g_Menu.keys[VK_RBUTTON] = true;
        break;
    case WM_RBUTTONUP:
        g_Menu.keys[VK_RBUTTON] = false;
        break;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        g_Menu.keys[wParam] = true;
        break;
    case WM_KEYUP:
        g_Menu.keys[wParam] = false;
        break;
    case WM_MOUSEWHEEL:
        if ((short)HIWORD(wParam) < 0)
        {
            cvar.m_Wheel_up = false;
            cvar.m_Wheel_down = true;
        }
        else
        {
            cvar.m_Wheel_down = false;
            cvar.m_Wheel_up = true;
        }
        break;

    default: break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot WM_CHAR.

Comment: Text input is far more complicated than tracking keys.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the current keyboard layout through [`GetKeyboardLayout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getkeyboardlayout), and then use [`ToUnicodeEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-tounicodeex) to convert the typed characters into corresponding Unicode characters.

Here is the implemented code snippet:

```
HHOOK _k_hook;
std::wstring text;
LRESULT __stdcall k_Callback1(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT key = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)lParam;

    //a key was pressed
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN && nCode == HC_ACTION)
    {
        TCHAR buffer[1024];
        HKL hkl = GetKeyboardLayout(GetCurrentThreadId());  //choose current keyboard layout
        BYTE uKeyboardState[256]{};
        ToUnicodeEx(key->vkCode, key->scanCode, uKeyboardState, buffer, 1024, 0, hkl);
        text += buffer;
        wcout << text << endl;;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```